# Is there a non-mobile based tool for testing ActiveSync?

Tags: exchange, internet-explorer, activesync

Is there any `ActiveSync` plugin for Internet Explorer or any Windows based tool that can be used to test whether or not clients can connect to our Exchange servers from outside our network?

Comment: Connect to exchange in what manner? IMAP? ActiveSync? OWA? RPC-over-HTTP(S)? SMB? POP? SMTP?

Comment: connect to exchange via ActiveSync but do not want to use a mobile phone. Is there any way to check whether users can access email or not without using a mobile phone?

Comment: So, are you trying to test from a specific client or test your setup from the outside in general?

Comment: Yes, i want to test from outside in general. so basically looking for a tool that can monitor the exchange ActiveSync. More specifically, need an IE plugin or windows based tool that can authenticate to activesync the same way a mobile user will do and make sure the connection is up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

## Try browser

You can visit `http(s)://YOURFQDNHERE/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync` to see if you get an authentication prompt. You can set up a script to keep checking this URL (and possibly log in) and see if you get a HTTP 501/505 response.

## Try PowerShell

If you're using Exchange 2007+, if you have the *Exchange Management Tools* installed on your test system, you can use the automate the `Test-ActiveSyncConnectivity` cmdlet to monitor whether or not ActiveSync is working properly. See the [2007 documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123540(v=exchg.80).aspx), [2010 documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123540(v=exchg.141).aspx), [2013 documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123540.aspx), or look for the cmdlet in newer versions of Exchange in the [TechNet library](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996058(v=exchg.150).aspx).

## Try RCA

For a one-time test, you can use the Exchange RCA (Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer) here: https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ to test your exchange setup from an outside perspective. It'll give you detailed feedback about any errors it encounters and will sometimes give you links to ways to fix common misconfigurations.

If there is still an issue with a client's ability to connect despite that tool working, then there's an issue with the client's setup or the client's ability to connect to your server from the network it's on.

## CLI test client exists

If you really want to get your hands dirty, you can build a CLI driven ActiveSync test client using source code from http://mobilitydojo.net/2010/03/30/rolling-your-own-exchange-activesync-client/, since all I see there right now is a GUI test client.

Comment: Thanks, i know about this tool. but forgot to mention that I'm looking for something that can be used to monitor ActiveSync exchange 24X7 without manual interference, something that is automatic and notify if it fails to connect.

Comment: Is there an issue with this tool that doesn't accomplish your goals?

Comment: Thanks, i know about this tool. but forgot to mention that I'm looking for something that can be used to monitor ActiveSync exchange 24X7 without manual interference, something that is automatic and notify if it fails to connect

Comment: Ah, that's a different question entirely!

Comment: yes, i should have mention that before. Are you aware of any tool that will help with this?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. This question is much more complex and open-ended... what are your requirements? Why are you trying to do this? One thing you can do is set up a monitor for port 443 (or 80, if you're not using encryption), since ActiveSync works over HTTP(S). This won't, however, tell you whether or not ActiveSync is "functional" on the server, but, if you can connect successfully, what are you doing to your server that would cause ActiveSync to fail???

Comment: I've found something that will help. Editing to provide details.

Comment: Requirement is to do client side monitoring to make sure the whole network is up and the clients can reach exchange all the time and notifies if there is any downtime  (just simple monitoring to make sure we get to know immediately if something is wrong).I looked at 'Firefox OS simulator' plugin but there is no way to automate it.

Comment: What version of exchange are you using?

Comment: 2010 exchange servers

Answer (score 0):

SCOM's Management Packs for Exchange (2007/2010/2013) offers the ability to setup synthetic transactions to measure availability (2007,2010). For 2013 it would seem that Exchange has it's own monitoring, which SCOM tracks.

If you're using on-prem Exchange 2013, look here:  [Managing Health Sets in Exchnage 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482054(v=exchg.150).aspx)

For Exchange 2010, the SCOM management pack can perform the following synthetic transactions: [Exchange MP Synthetic Transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758035(v=exchg.140).aspx)

Comment: Apologies if SCOM is too product-recommendy.  Seems like a lot of orgs that run Exchange own licensing for SCOM if they use it or not.  I tried to offer built-in Exchange tools as well.

Comment: Thanks can we automate this. we are using exchange 2010. Can you send me a link? I'm looking for something that can be used to monitor ActiveSync exchange 24X7 without manual interference, something that is automatic and notify if it fails to connect.

Comment: Thanks but this monitoring is not from a remote end. It will be good to have a tool/browser plugin that can simulate the email on a mobile phone and test ActiveSync to make sure users can access email.

Answer (score 0):

## Try MCA

There is the *Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer*. It's quite useful.

This is a downloadable [`ClickOnce`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) type stand alone application that is similar, but not identical to what the RCA (*Remote Connectivity Analyzer*, at https://TestConnectivity.Microsoft.com) can do.

- FAQ here: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj851141
- Installation from here. (I think you must use INTERNET EXPLORER. Otherwise the ClickOnce mechanism seems to fail.) http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=313783